# How to refresh content .Net C# (EXT.net) webforms application after update

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, browser-cache, ext.net

The problem that i faced is when I did an update to my application many things didn't refresh and many things was gone so I had to clear browser cache to get the content rendered right. I looked att the HTTP cache-control and it says "private".

My questions are
- How to refresh content or clear browser history after a code update?

- Is there any way to make for example a 24hours content timeout so the whole content refreshes after that timeout?
- And in which language it would be preferred to do it in C# or Javascript?
  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Either use METADATA tags in your header (taken from other stackoverflow answer)

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="Mon, 22 Jul 2002 11:12:01 GMT">
```

or

append your javascript urls with a timestamp (taken from other stackoverflow answer)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js?v=12392823"></script>
```

I've never had an issue with the Ext.net source coming from the axd handlers.